# Reload login rules without rebooting server

Tags: debian, pam

I have a Debian system where I've changed some PAM configuration, specifically:

```
$ cat /etc/security/access.conf
-:ALL EXCEPT root:ttyS1
```

I am expecting that only root is now able to login via serial, but after doing:

```
telinit -q
```

I can still login as a regular user on `/dev/ttyS1`.

How can I get init/PAM/login recognize my change without rebooting the machine?

Comment: it may need to reload the getty/login for the serial terminal. You might try killing the process and letting `init` respawn it.

Comment: [example](https://dpaste.de/T2HU). Basically you sometimes have to reload the daemon performing the authentication and in this case this means relaunching the login program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/security/access.conf` is consulted by the `pam_access.so` module only, which is not enabled in the stock PAM setup on Debian. Uncomment the

```
account  required       pam_access.so
```

line in `/etc/pam.d/login` (or wherever you want to use it). You needn't restart anything, it takes effect immediately.